# Storm Topology Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, apache-storm

I have a group of raspberries in which one of them is Pi2 and the others are Pi(Pi2 uses ARMv7 and other ARMv6). On Pi2 i run zookeeper, nimbus, ui (storm 0.10.0) and on the others I run supervisors (1 worker per device).

When I start the supervisors I get an error:

> Raspberry pi server vm is only supported on armv7+ vfp

I managed to bypass this error by setting as -client instead of -server at storm.py file. The problem begins when I submit a topology on the storm. Nimbus(which runs on Pi2) tries to assign the topology to the workers. The workers download the topology but I again encounter the same error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Server VM is only supported on ARMv7+ VFP

I run

> grep server * -R

in order to find if '-server' setting is used at the workers. I did not notice any crusial file that uses this setting (some logs indicated the server word).

So my question is how can I bypass the server option when a topology is submitted to the workers?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to patch the Storm source code and build Storm by yourself. It is hardcoded in https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/2b7a758396c3a0529524b293a9c773e974f70b56/storm-core/src/clj/backtype/storm/daemon/supervisor.clj#L1075